# How to create responsive background images similar to medium.com

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a rails web app using the foundation framework but am struggling to find a way to keep the image aspect ratio the way I would like it to be.

On [Medium.com](http://www.medium.com) they use full width background images on the homepage the way I would like it to work.

When resizing the browser from very wide to small the images initially scale maintaining the aspect ratio. They then seem to hit a minimum height and maintain that height whilst ensuring the width of the image doesn't distort. Finally, they use a media query to change the image for very small screens.

The part I am struggling on is setting a fixed height but ensuring it then doesn't distort horizontally when resizing the browser.

Any help people could offer to get the CSS working on the below HTML would really be much appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large12">
    <img src="assets/bg.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.image-src {
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

read more on [css-tricks Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

you can actually inspect all ellement using [Chrome DevTools — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) by **right clicking** and 
**inspect element**

[image]

in your case you have to use the image as background not as **img**

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

you want to use this :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large12">
    <!--<img src="assets/bg.jpg">-->
  </div>
</div>
```

then set

```
.row{
position: absolute;
background: #191918;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 447px;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

and

```
 .large12{
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

for reading and references please ckecout

1.[webplatform.org](http://www.webplatform.org/)

2.[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

3.[Codrops - Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/)

they all have very good tutorials never use **W3Schools** [read it here](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

They're using `background-size:cover`...

```
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

More about `background-size` here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size